# Can't get background-image:url to work

Tags: css, html, background-image

I've been trying to get an image to work with a navigation menu I'm working on. However, it seems no matter what I try, it doesn't display.

I've tried adding variations of...

```
display:block;
background-position:top left;
clear:both;
list-style-image:url
```

...from various google searches. I'm fairly new to HTML/CSS so I would appreciate any help or advice I can get. For reference, here is some HTML/CSS I'm working with.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="navigation">
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Bookmarks</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Top 100</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#navigation .menu {
background-image:url ('images/gradient_nav.png');
border-top-style:solid;
border-top-color:#DDD;
border-bottom:2px solid #ddd;
border-top-width:2px;
height:50px;
margin-top:-5px;
clear:both;
}
```

im using xampp to work on my local machine, my folder structure is:

```
htdocs\index.php
htdocs\css\style.css
htdocs\images\
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is your css located is inside a css folder? Or is it in the document root for your web server with the html file?

Comment: it is at htdocs/css, my images are at htdocs/images/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the url hast to be realative to the css file, not to the file where the css is included. you haven't given information about your folder-structure, but maybe it's like this:

```
index.html
images/gradient_nav.png
css/stylesheet.css
```

it so, the url hast to be `../images/gradient_nav.png` - resulting in this:

```
#navigation .menu {
  background-image:url ('../images/gradient_nav.png');
  border-top-style:solid;
  border-top-color:#DDD;
  border-bottom:2px solid #ddd;
  border-top-width:2px;
  height:50px;
  margin-top:-5px;
  clear:both;
}
```

Comment: ah sorry about not adding that information, my folder structure is:
`code`
xampp/htdocs/index.php 
htdocs/css/style.css
htdocs/images/gradient_nav.png (which is the file im trying to get to work)
`code`

Comment: theres nothing posted in you comment ;) - please add that information to your question directly by editing it instead of posting it in comments - that way other readers will see it, too.

Comment: seeing you folder structure it's exactly what i assumed. just add `../` to the image-url and everything will work (if so, please mark my answer as accepted by clicking the gray tick-mark to the left of it).

Comment: @ oezi i added ../ to the file path and it didn't seem to do anything, which is odd..

Edit: nevermind, the issue was adding ../ and removing the space between :url ('filepath'). Thank you! =)